# gnu make pattern rule matches the wrong rule

Tags: makefile

In the following example, when building all, the target main-gs-universalk9-m.o seems to match with rule 1 instead of rule 2. In make version 3.81 I thought order mattered. Even if I moved rule 2 to be defined before rule 1. It still ends up matching rule 1

What is the right way to code this and make it work as expected?

```
$(info .FEATURES := $(.FEATURES))


%.o:
    @echo "Rule 1 $?"
    rm -f $@
    cp $*.c $@

main-gs-%-m.o: file1.o file2.o file3.o
    @echo "Rule 2"
    cat $? > $@

binos_%_version.o:
    @echo "Rule 3"
    echo "Hello World" > $@

x86-%-m: main-gs-%-m.o binos_%_version.o
    @echo "Rule 4"
    cat $? > $@

all: x86-universalk9-m

clean:
    @echo "Rule Cleaning"
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f x86-universalk9-m
```

Comment: It might be because of the RHS on rule 2 *not* having any `%`s (it is the only rule like that).

Comment: If that rule was %.o: %c this seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at how the [implicit rule search algorithm](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search-Algorithm) works, you can see that it is performed in two stages.

During the first stage, make will drop any rules that have prerequisites that neither physically exist, nor "ought to exist". Files ought to exist if they are explicitly mentioned in the makefile as either a target, or as a prerequisite of an non-implicit rule.

Your rule `main-gs-%-m.o: file1.o file2.o file3.o` has three prerequisites, but as they do not exist, they aren't specified as explicit targets, and they only appear as prerequisites of implicit rules (i.e. this rule and the builtin implicit rules), the rule is dropped in favor of `%.o:` for `x86-universalk9-m`.

There are any number of ways to fix this although without knowing more about why you need to use all these pattern rules it's hard to give an exact answer, changing `%.o:` to `file1.o file2.o file3.o:` will work however.